# Concatenating strings in name attribute Struts

Tags: javascript, html, dom, struts

say the snippet `name="<%=(String) curItr.next()%>"` returns `shoppingList`. in a `html:text` tag.

how do i make it such that the DOM element will result with `shoppingList[0].anotherList[1]`? I tried

`name="<%=(String) curItr.next()%>" + shoppingList[0].anotherList[1]` but it doesn't quite work

full code snippet:

```
    <html:text indexed="true" name="<%=(String) 
curItr.next()%>"+"[0]" property="<%=(String) curItr.next()%>"/>
```

Comment: DOM element with what?

Comment: with just a string say "[0].anotherList[1]"

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: hi Roman, its an answer to your comment

Comment: It looks like you are trying to concatenate a javascript variable?

Comment: i would like to concatenate the value of the javascript variable with another string

Comment: ok, suppose it will work, using javascript to modify attribute of the DOM element, but what version of struts are you using, your structure seems complicated.

Comment: You should update to 2.3.15.2.

Answer (score 0):

It's unreadable and you should not use scriptlets, use JSTL for that.

```
<html:text property="propertyNameOfYourBean"/>
```

For list you should use `<c:forEach>` tag.